# How to show an objects traits when it is called from another piece of code as an instance

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I am just starting out with TraitsUI, and I am beginner Python programmer. I hope this question is not too low-level.

I want to display a button set up in ControlPanel, calling it from Main. When i do the following, i just a window with a button that says "Panel". If I click that button, i get another window with the "Start" button I want. How do i just get the window with the Start button?

Thanks,
Cosmo

Main:

```py
from enthought.traits.api import *
from enthought.traits.ui.api import *

class ControlPanel(HasTraits):
    """ This object is the core of the traitsUI interface. It hosts the method for
    interaction between the objects and the GUI.
    """

    start = Button("Start Measurements") 
    view = View(Item('start', show_label=False, style='custom' )) 

class MainWindow(HasTraits):
 """ The main window, here go the instructions to create and destroy the application. """

    panel = Instance(ControlPanel)
    def _panel_default(self):
        return ControlPanel()
    view = View(Item('panel'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow().configure_traits()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MainWindow`, change this:

```
    view = View(Item('panel'))
```

to this:

```
    view = View(Item('panel', style='custom'))
```

See the [InstanceEditor()](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/factories_basic.html#instanceeditor) documentation for more information.  The relevant part of that document is the paragraph below the screenshot.  The `simple` style for an `InstanceEditor` (which is the default style) creates a button that when clicked opens up a new window containing a view of the instance.  The `custom` style embeds the view of the instance in the same window that contains the item.  The screenshot in Fig. 36 shows an example.  The top of the screenshot shows the `simple` style, and below that is the `custom` style.  (And below that are the `text` and `readonly` styles, but they are not very useful except perhaps for debugging.)

Comment: THanks, that works! So simple. I read the InstanceEditor page, and am still unenlightened. Can you perhaps explain a bit more about what is going on? Thanks, DanG

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So it it the case that the configure_traits method invokes the InstanceEditor? I have seen examples the use editor=InstanceEditor in the Item(). Not sure why need to do that if it is invoked already by configure_traits...Hope I am making sense...